Docker Curl Error: couldn't resolve host name
I have someone set up docker in my machine and everything has been working smoothly until now. I just tried to pruned the volumes to free up some space. When i try to rebuild the iamge (forgive me if i am not using the correct terms here, as I am quite new to this and focus on data analysis part), i ran into the below errors.
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.python                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.70kB                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:latest                                                                                                                      2.0s
 => [auth] library/centos:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                            1.1s
 => => transferring context: 55.43MB                                                                                                                                                  1.0s
 => CACHED [ 1/16] FROM docker.io/library/centos:latest@sha256:a2                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [ 2/16] RUN dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos -y &&     dnf distro-sync -y                                              1.1s
------
 > [ 2/16] RUN dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos -y &&     dnf distro-sync -y:
0.949 CentOS Linux 8 - Extras                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
0.949 Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'extras':
0.949   - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=extras&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]
0.953 Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'extras': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=extras&infra=container [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]
------

 2 warnings found (use docker --debug to expand):
 - SecretsUsedInArgOrEnv: Do not use ARG or ENV instructions for sensitive data (ENV "DESTINATION_KEY") (line 64)
 - SecretsUsedInArgOrEnv: Do not use ARG or ENV instructions for sensitive data (ENV "SOURCE_KEY") (line 62)
Dockerfile.python:3
--------------------
   2 |
   3 | >>> RUN dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos -y && \
   4 | >>>     dnf distro-sync -y
   5 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos -y &&     dnf distro-sync -y" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I believe it is the line below in my docker file that is causing the error. How can I mitigate this ?
RUN dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos -y && \
    dnf distro-sync -y

Attaching the full Dockerfile.python script below. As @Evgenii Minikh mentioned centos is out of life, how should i modify the script ?
FROM centos:latest

RUN dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos -y && \
    dnf distro-sync -y

RUN yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y update && \
    yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y && \
    yum install openssl-devel libffi-devel bzip2-devel -y

RUN yum install wget -y && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/Python-3.9.7.tgz && \
    tar xvf Python-3.9.7.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.9*/ && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
    make altinstall

RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3.9 /usr/local/bin/pip3

ARG USER=centos
ARG V_ENV=boto3venv
ARG VOLUME=/home/${USER}/app-src

USER root

# RUN yum install -y epel-release

# RUN yum install -y \
#        python3-pip
# Upgrade pip
# RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# create user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ${USER}
USER ${USER}
WORKDIR /home/${USER}

# add credentials
RUN mkdir -p /home/${USER}/.aws
COPY aws/credentials /home/${USER}/.aws

RUN pip3 install virtualenv --user

# create virtual environment
RUN /home/${USER}/.local/bin/virtualenv ${V_ENV}

ENV PYTHONPATH=${VOLUME}

# set PATH to python3, pip3
ENV PATH=/home/${USER}/${V_ENV}/bin:$PATH

# install python packages using pip in the virtual environment
RUN mkdir -p ${VOLUME}
COPY requirements.txt ${VOLUME}
COPY src/ ${VOLUME}
RUN pip3 install -r ${VOLUME}/requirements.txt
#RUN pip3 install --upgrade -r ${VOLUME}/requirements.txt

# Run list files python
ENV SOURCE_BUCKET=
ENV SOURCE_KEY=
ENV DESTINATION_BUCKET=
ENV DESTINATION_KEY=
WORKDIR ${VOLUME}
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD ["--version"]


Did you set mirrorlist.centos.org anywhere explicitly? I can not resolve that address and that's what curl tells you.

Centos 7 is out of life since end of June 2024. They have disabled its repos and that's why there are errors connected with mirrorlist.centos.org. Here are some details about Centos 7 EOL: https://community.centminmod.com/threads/centos-7-end-of-life-eol-june-30-2024.25589/
Try to use these commands inside your container to disable mirrorlist:
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

You can try to add additional RUN section in your Dockerfile, like this:
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-* \
 && sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*


OP can't build their image, so they can't run commands inside the container. Your commands might be more useful as RUN statements to add to a Dockerfile.

i  tried this but still got the same error
